# Converting E-mail to Names

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting to create a script or figure out a formula that will allow me to do the following.

I am a teacher and often have student use Google Forms for quizzes and different surveys. When grading it I normally split their email. Occasionally some students will have a number after their last name.

firstname.lastname@stu.county.stateschools.us
I would like to take their e-mail and convert it to the following format.

lastname, firstname

This would allow me to sort easily and put into gradebook much faster.

The current best route I know of to do this is to split via . , @ then join the data I want.

This takes multiple different columns to complete my task that could very easily overwrite their data. I want this to all take place in one column and get rid of the extra information I do not need.

Comment: What programming language do you intend to use?

Comment: Javascript with Google Script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do that. I would probably start with the [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) `"@"`

- [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) the string to get the `"firstname.lastname"`
- Next, [split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string to separate the `firstname` and `lastname`
- Now [reverse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) the order of `["firstname", "lastname"]`
- Finally, [join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) them back together

```
 var email = "firstname.lastname@stu.county.stateschools.us";
 var index = email.indexOf('@');
 var name = email.slice(0, index).split('.').reverse().join(', ');

 // Logs "The student name is: lastname, firstname"
 Logger.log("The student name is: %s", name);
```

Comment: Thanks so much works like a dream!